# VLSM help required

Tags: networking

I have confused myself following a VLSM tutorial and need to get my understanding confirmed, would this be the correct format, or am i away off again

172.31.0.0
VLSM this network address for as many subnetworks as possible, with no more than 14 hosts in each subnetwork. Show the subnet mask used.

As the ip address is class b and contains 16 bits in the network portion, this means that we can have 2^16 = 65536 possible networks, to give each of these networks a maximum of 14 hosts we would use the subnet prefix \28 for each subnet.

Is this correct?

Thanks BB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Your subnet mast equates to 255.255.255.240 or /28. A total of 4096 subnets.

I admire your manual calculation however I forgot how to do it after a few nights sleep. Heres the quick and easy / cheat way to calculate subnets. http://www.subnet-calculator.com

However Its probably best you know it from manual calculation anyway - This just confirms your calculation.

Comment: :), learning for a cisco ccna qualification cant use a calculator when in exam conditions